# eclipse not working on ubuntu operating system

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-juno

hi i have downloaded eclipse juno linux version in my windows and transferred it to my ubuntu operating system.

when i click the eclipse launcher nothing happens,any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In what way did you transfer it? It could just be that. Why don't you just download it from your Ubuntu OS?

Comment: through usb,i have some problems with my internet connectivity in Ubuntu,so downloaded the Linux version in windows and got it transferred to my Ubuntu os.

Comment: If you can't connect to the Internet through Ubuntu, it might not download all the necessary items on Eclipse's first boot. Make sure that your version of Ubuntu and the Eclipse Linux version is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run windows executables on a linux machine.  You can download a version of eclipse for linux here: http://eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux